# SSRS: Table of group aggregates with grand total

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, grouping

I am using SSRS 2014. My end goal is to get a table that looks like the following:

```
Project Status     # of Projects    Oldest Project    Avg Project Age
Status 1                 27               82                16
Status 2                  9               29                 6
Status 3                 13              112                25
Status 4                 33               68                16
Status 5                  1               63                63
Status 6                  1               27                27
Grand Total              84              112                17
```

A table like this, including the grand totals, can be done in Excel using pivot tables (this is how the data was originally retrieved...manually...)

If I have the same source data in a table where my columns include `projectStatus` and `projectAge`, I could generate a query to get all but the grand totals in SQL:

```
SELECT projectStatus, COUNT(projectStatus), MAX(projectAge), AVG(projectAge)
FROM projects
GROUP BY projectStatus
```

If I wanted to add grand totals to that, I could do a `UNION` with the following query:

```
SELECT 'Grand Total', COUNT(projectStatus), MAX(projectAge), AVG(projectAge)
FROM projects
```

Note that the grand totals are calculated off of the entire dataset and not just the grouped data - this mostly applies to the average, because it just happens to work out for the `COUNT` and `MAX` columns.

Now, if I am trying to generate this above table in SSRS, it is easy to generate the above table *sans grand totals* using the former query. However, now **how do I add grand totals?**

---

I could instead try a different approach where I use a more generic dataset query like:

```
SELECT projectStatus AS statusCategory, projectAge AS daysInCurrentStatus FROM projects
```

And then use aggregate functions in my table and have SSRS do the aggregation itself and provide grand totals on the raw data. I get a new problem now. What is the correct way to set my table up? I am calling grouping by [statusCategory] as "Group1", using scoped aggregate functions like so:

[image: SSRS Scoped Group Aggregate Table Design]

And it correctly generates the grand totals, but now I have a new problem: it is showing the average *for each row* instead of just one cell per group/scope. **Is this something SSRS is meant to do, and if so, how can I do it?**

[image: SSRS Scoped Group Aggregate Table Preview (1)]

...

[image: SSRS Scoped Group Aggregate Table Preview (2)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mess around a little to get right layout, but you basically need a group header or footer to show the Group aggregates.

if you right click on the lines next to [statusCategory] and select `Insert Row > Outside Group - Above` it will create a group header for you.  Then just add your aggregate expressions in the correct columns like `=Count(Fields!projectStatus.Value)`  then you can just set Row Visibilty on the details row to hide if you dont want to see it.

you should end up with a layout similar to this.

[image]

with the middle row (detail) visibility set to false

Comment: You hit the nail man! Only, what I needed to do was `Insert Row > Inside Group - Above` instead of outside group. This worked exactly the way I had hoped.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You have two Row Groups right now. All you need to do is remove the inner one because it's not grouped by anything. In other words, it's repeating for every row of raw data.

So the Row Group named "Details" - either remove it or in the properties click "Add" and group it by 1. That will collapse those rows and do what you were expecting.